# Primitive subgroups with different order

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I have been studying the permutation group $S_{n}$ in combination with transitivity and blocks. Which leads to primitive groups.

Now I was wondering if for $n=6$, so $S_{6}$ could have two primitive subgroups of different order?

So I'm looking for $\tau\in{}S_{6}$ working on $B\subseteq{}S_{6}$ such that $\tau{}(B)=B$ or $\tau{}(B)\cap{}B=\emptyset{}$.

A block is trivial if $B=(1;...;6)$ or $|B|=1$.

If H is transitive and has only trivial blocks, it is called $primitive$.

So I'm looking for different subgroups of $S_{6}$ which are transitive, has only trivial blocks and have different order. Can anybody give me some help?

Thanx in advance!

(PS - How can I use accolades?)

Comment: have you done it for $S_4$. all hints will be there, where to look?

Comment: I thought I would delete my answer to this in case you haven't seen it yet, and you might like more chance to think about it yourself. In fact there are exactly four conjugacy classes of primitive subgroups of $S_6$, and they all have different orders. Two of them are easy and you really should be able to think of them yourself. The other two are not quite so obvious.

Comment: Okay, I have been thinking about it. So if we take $<(123456);(12)>\in{}S_{6}$. This subgroup only has trivial blocks, is transitive so is primitive. What is the order? And another primitive subgroups has to be transitive, so must contain a 6-cycle. (?) Can I put this 6-cycle with another block to create a new primitive subgroup? For example, $<(123456);(135)>$.

Comment: $\langle (1,2,3,4,5,6),(1,2) \rangle = S_6$ (it is well known that $\langle (1,2,3,\ldots,n),(1,2) \rangle = S_n$ for any $n$). Your second example, $\langle (1,2,3,4,5,6),(1,3,5) \rangle$ is imprimitive with blocks $\{1,3,5\},\{2,4,6\}$. It is not true that any transitive subgroup must contain a $6$-cycle. The other easy example of a primitive subgroup (other than $S_6$ itself) has no $6$-cycle because a $6$-cycle is an odd permutation.

Comment: So $<(1,2,3,4,5,6);(1,2)>=S_{6}$ is a primitive subgroup of $S_{6}$ of order $6!$. The alternating group of $A_{6}$ is another primitive subgroup of $S_{6}$. Let $a=<(1,2)(4,5)>$, $b=<(2,4)(4,5)>$ and $c=<(3,4)(5,6)>$. They have the same cycle type so they conjugate in $A_{6}$ and we have $abc=(1,2)(3,4)\cdot{}(2,4)(5,6)$. Thus $abcde=1$, it remains to show that they generate $A_{6}$. Can you agree with this?